# Azure Storage image upload not working correctly

Tags: php, azure

I have an issue with Azure Storage and I am not 100% sure how to fix it. I need to be able to take an image and upload it to a container. This is my first time using Azure Storage. Here is some of the code:

```
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';
require_once 'WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=buyeraudit;AccountKey=MYKEY';
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
```

here is another part:

```
$newFileName = $pro[0]['proid'] .'.'. $picExt;
rename($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $newFileName);
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("images", $newFileName,  file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['name']));
```

I just set the sdk up so it may also be an issue that has to do with that. I appreciate all help and thank you for helping.

Comment: See this: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/#how-to-upload-a-blob-into-a-container

Comment: Also: in the future, PLEASE BLUR THE CONNECTION STRING!

Comment: Finally: what error are you getting?

Comment: my errors:Warning: require_once(vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/submitted-product.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required "vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/smarty/libs') in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/submitted-product.php on line 5